# Sharepoint 2010 Email document in document library as an attachment

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a document Library in sharpoint. I see that I can email a link of a document in a library but is it possible to send the document as an attachment. I need to send the document to someone external to our company and they will not have access to sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable SMTP on the Server go to System Manager then click on Features then [SMTP](http://www.pcperformancenow.com) install it.  I have tested and this works on Windows 2008 Share Point 2010